# Less output now after SNMP update on 5 september 2019

Tags: updates, snmp

I work with Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

On 5 September 2019 `apt-get dist-upgrade` shows that the next updates were available: `libsnmp-base` `libsnmp30` `psmisc` `snmp` `snmpd`

Before the installation of this update, the `snmpwalk` command give the following output:

```
/usr/bin/snmpwalk --v 3 -u <account> -A  <password> 192.168.0.222.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3

iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.1 = STRING: "Physical memory"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.3 = STRING: "Virtual memory"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.6 = STRING: "Memory buffers"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.7 = STRING: "Cached memory"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.8 = STRING: "Shared memory"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.10 = STRING: "Swap space"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.31 = STRING: "/"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.36 = STRING: "/dev/shm"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.38 = STRING: "/run"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.39 = STRING: "/sys/fs/cgroup"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.58 = STRING: "/boot"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.59 = STRING: "/home"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.60 = STRING: "/run/user/1000"
```

---

After the update, the `snmpwalk` command now returns the following output:

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.1 = STRING: "Physical memory"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.3 = STRING: "Virtual memory"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.6 = STRING: "Memory buffers"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.7 = STRING: "Cached memory"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.8 = STRING: "Shared memory"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.10 = STRING: "Swap space"
```

So, the lines with the disk partitions are missing after the update.

Do you have a solution?

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

When this is a bug, what is the official channel to report this?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been reported as a bug and is being fixed. I was seeing the same thing you were on our patched 16.04 LTS servers.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/net-snmp/+bug/1843036

Comment: Fine that the bug is being fixed. 
But when and where can I find and download the fix?

Comment: The fix was released on 9/12, so just run an upgrade to install it. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`